# Showing inline admin form for GenericForeignKey relationships in django

Tags: django, generic-foreign-key

my models.py

```
class PagePlaceholder(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey()
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    display_content = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Page(models.Model):
    page_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000,default="sample_page")
    placeholder = models.ManyToManyField('PagePlaceholder')
```

the placeholder can refer to any of 4 classes by the generic foreign key relationship.
page has a many2many relationship to placeholder to say that a page can contains a bunch of different models.

and my admin.py for the same.

```
class PagePlaceholderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class PageInline(GenericStackedInline):
    model = PagePlaceholder

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PageInline,]
```

now what i want is in the page admin view, to show the form for editing the pageplaceholder's display content object. trying to get that inline gives me an error saying that object is not a class.
is there a decent solution for this with the admin.py or is it necessary for me to create a new form and view to display these model forms properly?

Comment: can you include the stacktrace, thanks

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/jschrewe/django-genericadmin? I have the same issue.

Comment: i think i sorted this issue by adding a "through" models and specifying that to be inline.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm checking!